# Does not use library from another module of same project in Idea

Tags: jakarta-ee, intellij-idea, wildfly

I have a rather small project, consisting of one stateless EJB + one servlet.
EJB should collect data from MongoDB.
Servlet should inject these EJBs.
That's all.

I have included **mongo-java-driver** in project libraries. Everything compiles fine, but on deploy stage one of the modules fail with

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bson.conversions.Bson
```

this class is located in mongo-java-driver.

Idea generates two artifacts: One has META-INF and both classes (servlet and ejb). The second artifact contains WEB-INF and again both classes and **lib** directory with mongo-java-driver.

Should I somehow add mongo-java-driver to first artifact? Or to extend scope that driver becomes available to first artifact?

Tried to add META-INF/lib/mongo-java-driver.jar manually - it didn't help.

If a remove EJB and work with mongo from servlet - everything is fine.

Comment: any chance you can post your project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import mongo-java-driver from the ejb module. WAR classes are isolated, so ejb module [cannot use them](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Class+Loading+in+WildFly):

> The ear-subdeployments-isolated element value has no effect on the
>   isolated classloader of the .war file(s). i.e. irrespective of whether
>   this flag is set to true or false, the .war within a .ear will have a
>   isolated classloader and other sub-deployments within that .ear will
>   not be able to access classes from that .war. This is as per spec.

If you package both your ejb and war modules into ear - the right place for mongo-java-driver.jar would be `<ear-root>/lib`

See also: [Class Loading in Deployments](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.1/html/Development_Guide/chap-Class_Loading_and_Modules.html#Class_Loading_in_Deployments)

Comment: I couldn't find how can I "import mongo-java-driver from the ejb module in Idea. But packaging both artifacts to single EAR solved the problem and Idea automagically added lib directory with mongo-driver. Many thanks!

Comment: When you have a maven project and package ejb and war into a single ear - you have 3 pom.xml files: parent for ear, and children for ejb and war. So, you can add a dependency to ejb's pom.xml or to war's pom.xml. In the latter case ejb module cannot use this dependency as it will packaged to war and isolated. This is why I suggested to " import mongo-java-driver from the ejb module".

Comment: I do not use maven (yet), because it repeats Idea's functionality and is very unfriendly. Luckily your advice helped to fix problem with Idea.

Comment: In fact, idea is very well integrated with maven - it can import maven projects and synchronize its settings with pom.xml on the fly. If you use maven - you don't depend on any particular ide (suppose you colleague loves eclipse:)